# Reverting to portrait after Done pressed on movie player?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I've got a MPMoviePlayer working. It is designed to show a postage-stamp size movie as a subview in the view. When the phone is rotated into landscape, it goes into full screen mode. And when the phone is in portrait it goes into postage-stamp portrait mode.

The only problem is when I press Done when in landscape mode, it stays in landscape, with the postage stamp sized movie, rather than kick back into portrait..

Here's some of my code:

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration { 


    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || toInterfaceOrientation ==  UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        [moviePlayerController setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
    } else
    {
        [moviePlayerController setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];

    }


}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

        return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;

}
```

How would I get it to kick into portrait mode after pressing Done?

Answer (score 2):

@cannyboy...you just need to use below method in your APPDelegate.m if your application only works with portrait mode

```
- (NSUInteger) application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
if ([[window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class]])
{
    //NSLog(@"in if part");
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
else
{
    //NSLog(@"in else part");
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}}
```

Comment: If I use this code, everything works fine except one important thing - when I click on "Done" button while in landscape, I see my view controller in landscape too after video player shuts down.

Comment: please let me know you have comment all code except this one related to orientation or not ? if not then pls comment it's working here fine.

Comment: Thanks, it finally worked! I've missed one line of code, deleted it - and everything was fine! I'll give you your bounty in 6 hours.

Comment: Thanks I'll wait for this enjoyeeee:)

Answer (score 1):

I was the same problem and now I am telling you how I solved it. I don't know the below method is right or wrong but it work fine.

- Instead of opening `MPMoviePlayer` in view open it in a new `viewController`. I mean create a new `UIViewController` to show the movie and push it some how so that user will not understood that they are redirecting into a new screen.
- Disable the parent screen for landscape mode and allow `MovieViewController` to landscape.
- When user press the done button or close button simply `pop` the `viewController` and as the previous screen don't support landscape mode so the screen will automatically shows in portrait mode.

Comment: you don't need to create new view controller Please check my below answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                  selector:@selector(_moviePlayerWillExitFullscreen:)
                                         name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification object:nil];


- (void)_moviePlayerWillExitFullscreen:(NSNotification *)notification 
{
    CGFloat ios = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
    CGFloat min = 5.0;
    if (ios >= min)
    {
        if (self.interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
        {  
            if([self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait])
            {
                [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
                [self willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation duration:0];
                [UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];
            } 
        }
    }   
}
```

Note that this only works in ios 5.0 and later, and you will get a warning that setOrientation is not supported, but it works pretty well

Answer (score -1):

One way you could try is to force your device to think it is in portrait mode.  To do this, try using:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait];
```

If you do not want your device to show landscape while not playing a movie, you will also have to add some logic to your code that you have shown above to only change to landscape if the movie is playing.

Comment: Do not use that method, it is undocumented and part of a private API - hence reason for being rejected.