# MpMovie Player not rotating to land scape mode

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, mpmovieplayer, ios6.1

Right now  my project contains 4 tabbars and in fourth tabbar i have a button,if we press that button we need to play a movie.My project is in potrate mode and am not able to rotate the mpmovieplayer to landscape.

Comment: Check this link for rotate `movieplayer` [Click this link here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960665/mpmovieplayercontroller-re-orientation-portrait-to-landscape-and-back-to-portrai

Comment: Actually in my case am using tabbars

Comment: Means rotate with tabbar ?

Comment: and doesn't effect tabbar in mpmovieplayer rotation.

Comment: In one tabbar we will have one button if we press that button am using present modal view for showing mpplayer

Comment: check this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019200/how-to-rotate-an-mpmovieplayercontroller

Comment: in this link they use a present model view for Mpmovieplayer

Comment: Also this Link For tabbar Based so please check this link https://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/63029-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-and-tabbar.html

Comment: Please check my below posting: [For manage rotation of mpmovie player](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22005333/1728580)

Answer (score 0):

Show this image [image: Show image here]

show and check your supported interface orientation in your detail and click on landscape orientation.